# How to add custom tab to CMS selection in magento admin menu

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

Please help me.
I have my module - Feedback. I want to add tab to CMS selection in magento admin menu, that would be like this CMS->Feedback.

In this tab I want show grid of received messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write this code in your module config.xml file.

```
<config>
     <adminhtml>
       <menu>
         <cms>
             <children>
                 <feedback module="feedback">
                     <title>Feedback</title>
                     <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                     <action>feedback/adminhtml_feedback</action>
                 </feedback >
             </children>
        </cms>

    </menu>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```